# WCF Service works on localhost but gives endpoint error on server

Tags: c#, wcf

I have 2 services and a test console app to test them with.

TestConsole2 (the test console) has a Service Reference to the service RequestsStub. RequestsStub has a service reference to RequestServices.

RequestsStub simply calls the methods from RequestServices.

So visually....

TestConsole2 -> RequestsStub -> RequestServices

So, I hosted RequestServices on a server and had RequestsStub and TestConsole2 local. It all worked nicely. As soon as I changed RequestsStub on the server, I get the error....

> There was no endpoint listening at http://urlremoved.on.ca/Requests/RequestService.svc that could attempt the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details

Any ideas or knowledge to point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:
Config file for RequestServices...

```xml
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="RequestServices.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RequestServices.Properties.Settings.RequestServicesConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=DEVSQL;Initial Catalog=RequestServices;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=webdev;Password=removed"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommunicationService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://urlremoved.on.ca/Communication/CommunicationService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICommunicationService"
        contract="serviceCommunication.ICommunicationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommunicationService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RequestServices.RequestServiceBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

 <applicationSettings>
  <RequestServices.Properties.Settings>
   <setting name="LogSource" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Request Services Service</value>
   </setting>
   <setting name="LogType" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Application</value>
   </setting>
  </RequestServices.Properties.Settings>
 </applicationSettings>


</configuration>
```

And the config for the RequestsStub...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRequestService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://urlremoved.on.ca/Requests/RequestService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRequestService"
        contract="RequestsServiceReference.IRequestService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IRequestService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RequestsStub.RequestServicesStubBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: How are you hosting the Stub? What is the relevant bit of config for that service? Can you open the MEX / WSDL for it? Have you checked firewall issues?

Comment: Added the config files to my original question. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Jeroen I'm not sure what you mean by "How are you hosting the Stub"... sorry.

I can open the WSDL, and I'm not sure what firewall issues I would check for.

Comment: Are you self-hosting, hosting in WAS or IIS, etc. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx)

Comment: Careful btw, note that you disclosed your (development) password in your last edit.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about the password.